# Generate mapping.txt with Proguard

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Ho to generate the mapping file with Proguard enabled ?

Here is my config file proguard.cfg :

```
-keep class mono.MonoRuntimeProvider { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.MonoPackageManager { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.MonoPackageManager_Resources { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.android.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.java.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.javax.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk.platform.android.AndroidGameView { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk.GameViewBase { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk_1_0.platform.android.AndroidGameView { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk_1_0.GameViewBase { *; <init>(...); }

-keep class android.runtime.** { <init>(***); }
-keep class assembly_mono_android.android.runtime.** { <init>(***); }
# hash for android.runtime and assembly_mono_android.android.runtime.
-keep class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keepclassmembers class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; <init>(...); }


/* some code ... */

-printmapping mapping.txt
```

I get these warnings :

```
PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [formsviewgroup.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
PROGUARD : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
```

More details here :
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79813/generate-mapping-txt-with-proguard

Answer (score 1):

`Xamarin.Android` includes a `-dontobfuscate` in it's `proguard_xamarin.cfg` and thus mapping for obfuscated Java stack traces would be turned off even if you include `-printmapping`

#### `proguard_xamarin.cfg` (Xamarin.Android Version: 7.0.1.3)

```
# This is Xamarin-specific (and enhanced) configuration.

-dontobfuscate

-keep class mono.MonoRuntimeProvider { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.MonoPackageManager { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.MonoPackageManager_Resources { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.android.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.java.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.javax.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk.platform.android.AndroidGameView { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk.GameViewBase { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk_1_0.platform.android.AndroidGameView { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk_1_0.GameViewBase { *; <init>(...); }

-keep class android.runtime.** { <init>(***); }
-keep class assembly_mono_android.android.runtime.** { <init>(***); }
# hash for android.runtime and assembly_mono_android.android.runtime.
-keep class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keepclassmembers class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; <init>(...); }

# Android's template misses fluent setters...
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.view.View {
   *** set*(***);
}

# also misses those inflated custom layout stuff from xml...
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.view.View {
   <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet);
   <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int);
}
```

FYI: Thus warning, are just that, warning. Duplicate zip entries for resources are usually harmless. If you have a need to include one duplicated resource over another, you would need to remove (or rename) the unneeded ones.

Comment: OK, so it isn't possible to generate mapping file with Xamarin ? Or exists there a solution to edit proguard_xamarin.cfg file ?

Comment: @NilkOne Without obfuscation of the Java code, there is no purpose in a mapping file as it provides a way to map Java ART/Dalvik stack traces of obfuscated code to non-obfuscated Java code. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an APK on Play Store, but error reports indicate errors in stacktrace in filename like "3322d0afd39449b787c0cfbf5bb901ef" or "md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f".
So I would like to know which files are buggy.

Comment: @NilkOne Proguard mappings will have nothing to do with that. Names like `md5....` come from the creation of md5sum namespaces of Android callable wrappers when you do not use `Name` attribute on your classes, I would *highly* recommend using a crash reporting in your app, like HockeyApp, the Xamarin Insight replacement, in order to get decoded C# stacktraces from your app's crashes. https://www.hockeyapp.net

Comment: what about [that](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281?hl=en) ? OK for HockeyApp, we use already our crash reporting but it show us correct names when app is in debug mode but show "3322d0afd39449b787c0cfbf5bb901ef" in "release mode"

Comment: do you have an idea ?

Comment: About which? The link you provided is about when using Proguard and deobfuscating Java stack traces, not relevant for C# stack trace crashes. Are you  trying to trace a Java crash or a C# Managed Stack Trace?

Comment: @NilkOne Are you using HockeyApp? or smoother crash reporter?

Comment: @NilkOne And files such as `3322d0afd39449b787c0cfbf5bb901ef` would be usually from libraries where there are no "filenames"; 3rd party, .Net system libs, etc... Services such as HockeyApp can give you line numbers and filenames of YOUR `Xamarin.Android` code, if you are compiling with `AndroidManagedSymbols` set to true. For iOS you would need the dSYM for symbolizing. You can also take an Android crash from Logcat and use `mono-symbolicate` on it...

Comment: You're right about Java Stack Trace, so I think it's not possible to use Google crash reports of Google Dev Console (Android Market), is'nt it ?
I'm not using HockeyApp, I use our custom crash reporter in Android MainActivity of our Xamarin.Forms App by using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser.
We use a custom crash reporter because we wan't to send some app user settings, I don't know if it's possible to choose what informations to send with the crash report ?

Comment: @NilkOne In that case using a custom `TraceWriter` to output the full C# stack trace that includes the MVID and AOTID metadata and appending that to the crash report would be the only way I can think you could do it. You could then use that text from the crash report and using mono-symbolicate along with the original build symbols (msym) you can get a full C# managed stack trace... Using a 3rd-party crash reporting service that already supports Xamarin might be easier...